# SSIS Flat File Import to SQL Server - All Files Flowing through Error Path

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I am importing a .csv file to sql via SSIS.  All is going ok although the file that we are trying to import is not what I would call "clean".  I can't do anything about that as it is from another company.  I have therefore created an error table in SQL as well as the table for the import.

Basically all of the files (over 14000) flow into the error table.  I have opened the .csv file in Excel and although some of the rows have blanks spaces instead of NULLs, there are some that I thought would have gone through.
looking at the error codes I get the following:

In my data flow there is a fLat file Source with error out put going to ole db destination
The data flow from the flat file source goes to a derived column to add a column with the System Start Date and then on to a ole db destination.

Nothing too fancy I though

ErrorCode - -1071607675
ErrorColumn - 211

All columns in the sql table where the rows are supposed to be imported are (varchar(1500), null)
Looking at the import file iself with SSIS the DataType for the columns are string[DT_STR] with output column width of 150 which I though would be ok.

The plan is to import the majority of the data and then have a data steward look at the erros to import manually or something similar from the SQL2012 3 column error output which I must say is pretty poor really although that is a different matter.

I can't figure out why not even one of these rows will import in to the correct sql table?

Answer (score 0):

errcode equates to error C0209085 which is **The data was truncated**. Unless you're handling truncation then this is a fatal message. Either ignore truncation or debug run with a data viewer to identify truncating entries.

Answer (score 0):

This was a date time issue.  Manipulation of the .csv file before import resolved.  Date changed from YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD.

Many thanks.